# Wix toolset use var in condition

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to run a custom action only if a certain var equals "".
How can I use a var in a condition? or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do (like setting the var in a property which feels a bit ugly)?
This is what I've tried so far:

```
<Custom Action="SomeCA">$(var.SomeVar) = ""</Custom>
<Custom Action="SomeCA"><![CDATA[$(var.SomeVar) = ""]]></Custom>
```

Both don't work - getting an error from light.exe: Bad conditional string

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a property is set to an empty string ("") the result is that the property is deleted. So, if you're trying to check if `MYPROPERTY = ""`, what you really want is to check for `Not MYPROPERTY`.